# Switch in parallel to a hvdc load. Fail or success?

Tags: motor, switches, relay, hvdc

Suppose I have 600v dc as my power source to a motor. And I have a isolation relay in parallel with the motor. The motor runs when the switch is open. What happens when the switch is closed?

Would something burnout? 
Or would this switching operation work just fine?

Comment: Schematic would help here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your circuit is below, this will NOT work -- once the relay closes, you'll short out your power supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUqeEy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Jim. But what if I add a power resistor in series with the switch. Would it work then, I'm trying to make this parallel switching work

Comment: Yes, as long as it was suitably rated... But what is the purpose of this? I'm not sure what you could gain besides a bunch of wasted power (600^2 / R)

Comment: If you are trying to stop the motor when the switch is closed, this won't work, with or without a resistor in series with the switch.  Without a resistor, the current through the relay will (hopefully) blow the 600 V circuit breaker (which will stop the motor, but is probably not what you want to do - we should never intentionally blow breakers).